# Community - Search for Article Returns No Results

Tags: community, search, articles

I have a Napili template when I enter a string in the search box and click 'Search', nothing is found.  The type-ahead feature is returning articles.  If I click on Topics, then Articles are displayed.  I have another Community that is working as expected, and I have compared all the configuration settings I can think of and I don't see any differences.  Do you know I am doing wrong?

Comment: you can share the screenshot of the Search component and this looks like some attribute in builder is not set properly .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Verify the Builder parameters for the Search Results Components

[image]